# Expression of type [UIViewController]? unused

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I just migrated to Xcode 8.0 and from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0.

I've got a UITableViewController with this method:

```
@IBAction func cancelToLastLevelNavigationController(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

    // go back to last table view controller
    let count = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController((self.navigationController?.viewControllers[count! - 1])!, animated: true)
}
```

Now XCode is telling me "Expression of type [UIViewController]? unused" and points to the first "p" of "popToViewController".

Why? The method still does what it should do.

Comment: Please, why are you downvoting for this question? stackoverflow did not show me the other question despite the similar topic. It's not my fault.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController...
```

Your code works exactly the same, and the warning goes away.

Comment: I had to clean the project after the change, but than it indeed worked and the warning was gone! Thanks!

Comment: @Nina See if it now works without the `_ =`. I'm curious about this. Apple has waffled about this warning during the course of the development of Swift 3...

Comment: The warning reappears when I try it without the "_ =".

Comment: Thanks. So they are serious about this one. :) The `_ =` means "I am _deliberately_ ignoring the result of this call" and thus satisfies the compiler.

Comment: If my answer was right and helped you, please accept it (click the checkmark so that it is filled in). I notice that you have _never_ accepted an answer. That is very incorrect behavior on Stack Overflow. You should go back through _all_ your past questions and accept an answer where appropriate.

Comment: Where do I accept an answer? Because I upvoted already, isn't that enough?

Comment: You did subsequently accept it. Do you see the difference? This is _not_ the same as upvoting. Also, did you notice that when you accept, _you gain reputation_? It is greatly to your advantage to accept answers. You gain reputation, plus people will be very reluctant to help you if they cannot count on you to accept an answer. We are here to help each other and provide a database of assistance for future users, but reputation is still the basis of the "economy" of the game we are playing here.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about this.